# Unable to create WhatsApp account from Facebook Business Manager

Tags: java, facebook, api, whatsapp

i want to integrate Whatsapp Business API from facebook business manager.

As per the steps to create WhatsApp account, given in blog (https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2087193751603668?id=2129163877102343)

**Steps done by me :**

- First i was created Facebook Business Manager account.
- Then i was completed business verification in Business Manager.
- As per above blog , after business verification **"Whatsapp Account" option** will **enabled** for me.like this image.
  ([Whatsapp accounts option is enable (option show)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qshld.jpg))
- Here my business verification verified successfully.but after successfully verification **i cant able to show "Whatsapp Accounts" option**.like this image
  ([Whatsapp accounts option is not show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbEP8.png))

However, I don't see link of "WhatsApp Accounts" in "Accounts" section though my business is verified here.
I don't how to proceed ahead without "WhatsApp Accounts" link.

Please guide us for further steps for creating "WhatsApp Accounts" and get the certificate.

Comment: your problem does not require any coding based solution so i don't see any point in posting here

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you found out how to do it?

Comment: same issue. any idea?

Comment: did you try https://moonmail.io ?

Comment: We have the same problem. @Harsh Patel Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

**I also faced the same problem, this is how I solved it:**

1. Goto your business verification detail & you will see the business phones numbers.
2. You just create a whatsapp business account from the business phone
   no. (Currently your business phone no. is not registered with
   whatsapp business account)

***After that you create the whatsapp bussiness acc. from the business phone no. you will see the whatapp account option in Account section in business settings.***

Comment: I am facing the same problem and just created the WhatsApp business in by mobile with the registered business phone number, but still no WhatApp account option in the FB Business Setting.

Comment: Seems that this solution is not working or the UI is completely different right now